# <sup> tag not working in WordPress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, superscript

I am trying to use Trademark & Registered/Copyright symbols smaller in a WordPress site, but doing some of the standard methods for CSS were not working, and using what I have below maybe somebody has an idea on how I could expand.

**Traditional/Normal way I would have done this:**

`Awesomesauce <sup>&reg;</sup>` would look like `Awesomesauce®` (the R is smaller than other text).

In the theme I am using, it was not doing that with that tag
[image]

I then tried `<span style="font-size:6px;">` just see if it would do anything different.  No luck.

So, I then approached it from a JavaScript side of things.
I started with my H1 tag

```
jQuery(function($){
  var $el = $(".section_header .post_title"); 
  var t = $el.text(); 
  t = t.replace('®','<sup>®</sup>');
  $el.html(t);
});
```

[image]

Since that works, how would I make the same work for body text because I cannot get it to work using the following code

```
jQuery(function($){
  var $el = $(".wpb_text_column .wpb_wrapper p"); 
  var t = $el.text(); 
  t = t.replace('®','<sup>®</sup>');
  $el.html(t);
});

jQuery(function($){
  var $el = $(".section_header .post_title"); 
  var t = $el.text(); 
  t = t.replace('®','<sup>®</sup>');
  $el.html(t);
});
```

What the HTML section looks like:
[image]

Comment: check that element exists when you run the code `console.log($el.length)`. Otherwise create a demo that reproduces problem

Comment: The code seems right for the markup, and it should work, so this is probably something Wordpress specific, dynamic elements etc. -> https://jsfiddle.net/og4sfd6k/

Comment: _"In the theme I am using..."_ What theme is that? I'm almost 100% sure that is your theme style that is overwriting the default properties for the `<sub>`tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very normal that `WP themes` overwrite default browser style.
Try adding this to your ***custom.css*** file:

```
sup {
    vertical-align: super;
    font-size: smaller;
}
```

If you don't use custom style or child theme <sup>*([Why use a Child Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#Why_use_a_Child_Theme.3F))*</sup>
Then, add that code at the very bottom of your *theme style css file*.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your issue is WordPress not recognizing the "sup" element.  I support a few WordPress sites and "sup" works just fine whenever I use it.  In your case, it appears that you are trying to use javascript (jQuery in particular within your WordPress site.  WordPress does not process javascript reliably when found within a page.  The documentation that I have read states that it is  unsupported to use your own javascript on WordPress pages.  However, I have succeeded in using Javascript in some pages within my WordPress site but with rather inconsistent results overall.  I recommend that you format your text directly within the WordPress WYSIWYG editor as follows:

AWESOMESAUCE<sup>&reg;</sup>